# How to set headers in python selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I cant find how to set request headers within selenium chrome webdriver (python). I need to set "host" header. I tryed that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities


url = 'http://localhost:888/test'

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
desired_capabilities['chrome.page.customHeaders.host'] = 'test.local'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/tmp/chromedriver',
                          desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

driver.get(url)
```

And result:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:888
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

So, I expected header `host:test.local` but found that `Host: localhost:888`

What I am doing wrong? I cant find how to set headers with Chrome webdriver :(

Answer (score -1):

`Host` in the request header is the name of the *server* (destination), and that's set by your `driver.get(url)`.

`Host` request header is constructed from the serverUrl using nodejs `url.parse(serverUrl)`. So you cannot send the request to server "a", with the Host header set to "b".

This means if your server is being hosted on your local computer, you can (likely) access it as `http://localhost:888/test`, in which case your header will include:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:888
```

or access it as `http://127.0.0.1:888/` resulting in

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:888
```

or access it as `http://Johns-iMac.local:888/test`... assuming you're using an iMac whose hostname is "Johns-iMac.local":

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: Johns-iMac.local:888
```

or access it using your network interface IP address, perhaps `http://192.168.1.5:888/test`:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.5:888
```

And this is the key to your solution: You need to access it using the URL `http://test.local:888/test`.

So what you want to do is *modify DNS* so that your computer thinks  host `test.local` has an IP address of `127.0.0.1` (or whatever you prefer).

Doing this depends on your OS, but commonly, it's simply adding a line to the end of your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
test.local    127.0.0.1
```

(you may need to reboot).

From now on, all requests to `test.local` will be sent to the server at `127.0.0.1` and `http://test.local:888/test` will give you the *request header*:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: test.local:888
```

- **NOTE**: I say your server will "likely" respond to any/all of these different requests. That's true, assuming it's configured to respond to a default host, or configured with a VirtualHost (Apache) or Server Block (nginx) which matches whatever host you're attempting to access.

Comment: I need to send request to localhost with different `host` headers. How can I do that?

Comment: So the server thinks your browser is somewhere else? You can't, not really. You don't send YOUR host name to the server, rather it's a TCP connection, which means the server will get your IP address. The server may do a reverse lookup to attempt to determine hostname from IP, but not automatically. Proxies allow you to "change" you IP by using intermediate routing, but that doesn't sound like what you're looking for either.

Comment: Currently researching the same issue. Looking to discover how you would provide a referrer to your opened webpage in selenium tests, the app being opened uses the referrer and that is undefined as there is no referrer to the app from the test suite.